# Applying different functions to different columns of grouped dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to Pandas. I have grouped a dataframe by date and applied a function to different columns of the dataframe as shown below

```
def func(x):
        questionID = x['questionID'].size()
        is_true  = x['is_bounty'].sum()
        is_closed = x['is_closed'].sum()
        flag = True
        return pd.Series([questionID, is_true, is_closed, flag], index=['questionID', 'is_true', 'is_closed', 'flag'])

df_grouped = df1.groupby(['date'], as_index = False)
df_grouped = df_grouped.apply(func)
```

But when I run this I get an error saying

```
questionID = x['questionID'].size()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.
```

When I do the same thing this way it doesn't give any error.

```
df_grouped1 = df_grouped['questionID'].size()
```

I don't understand where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`'int' object is not callable.` means you have to use `size` without `()`

```
x['questionID'].size
```

For some objects `size` is only value, for others it can be function.
The same can be with other values/functions.